# rspec: test if a method is called from a method

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to test if the method foo1 is called from foo. Here is my code

```
class C 

    def foo1
        puts "called"
    end 

    def foo
        puts foo1
    end 

end




describe C
    it "called"
            expect(C.new.foo).to receive(:foo1)
    end
end
```

But i am getting below error on line `expect(foo_).to receive(:foo1)`:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: You need a `do` to complete your block. `it "called" do`

Comment: Likewise for `describe C do`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
class C 
  def foo1
    puts "called"
  end 

  def foo
    puts foo1
  end 
end



describe C do
  it "called" do
    c = C.new
    expect(c).to receive(:foo1)
    c.foo
  end
end
```

- The `describe` and `it` blocks need complete `do ... end` syntax in order to be valid language.
- Fixed your expectation. Reading the code is fairly self-explanatory, but basically you need to define your expectation against the correct object.
- ([Style-guide compliance](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)) Use two spaces per indentation level (aka soft tabs). No hard tabs.